# Can Marketing Cloud subscribe to an Event Bus?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does anyone know of a way to subscribe to an external Event (Pub/Sub) to bring data into Marketing Cloud? Is it possible to do this? I've looked into Event Notification Service (ENS), but it seems it's covering only internal events and only transactional ones. Can I connect to an event bus or API/FTP is the only way to bring data into the system?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's not possible. You will need some middleware, which will subscribe to events, and facilitate the integration by passing on the data to the native APIs of Marketing Cloud